# Binding ListViewItem Background to boolean

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers, styles

Probably a simple one but i can't seem to get it to work, here's the XAML for the listview and bindings;

```
<ListView 
   VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
   x:Name="lstTrackers" 
   ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MainWindowViewModel.TrackerCollection}" 
   HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
   <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
         <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=LastTransmitted}" Value="True">
               <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=LastTransmitted}" Value="False">
               <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
            </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
   </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock 
            Text="{Binding Path=Description}" 
            x:Name="listTextClick" 
            MouseLeftButtonUp="listTextClick_MouseLeftButtonUp" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

and the property that i'm trying to bind it to;

```
 public class TrackerViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        readonly Tracker _tracker;

        public TrackerViewModel(Tracker tracker)
        {
            _tracker = tracker;
        }

        public bool LastTransmitted
    {
        get
        {
            return _tracker.lastTransmitted;
        }
        set
        {
            _tracker.lastTransmitted = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("LastTransmitted");
        }
    }
    }
```

And then i'm simply trying to set the boolean to true, which i assumed would trigger the style to proc;

```
  _trackerViewModel.LastTransmitted = true;
```

However, nothing at all seems to happen. Is there something simple yet imperative that i'm missing?

Note: I've already tried changing "true" to "True", just incase.

Edit 1: It seems that the change isn't being notified, which is very strange because i'm certain it was. If i change the trigger to;

```
<Style x:Key="listBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=LastTransmitted}" Value="True">
                                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                                                        </DataTrigger>
                                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=LastTransmitted}" Value="False">
                                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" ></Setter>
                                                    </DataTrigger>
                                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                                    <!--<Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>-->
                                                </Style>
```

Then the textblocks are all blue, as denoted by the boolean being set to true. However When it is set to true, and the property is notified, nothing changes. Perhaps the list isn't refreshing properly? I'm sure it's linked to a ObservableCollection.

EDIT 2: and on that note, it turns out i'm using a custom list; "ThreadedBindingList". It might not be updating from the OnNotify..so i'll have to try working around this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to raise the `PropertyChangedEvent` for the property `LastTransmitted`, so that the UI gets notified that the property has changed and your Triggers are executed.

Since you inherit your class from `ViewModelBase` I assume that the class implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and provides a method to raise the event.

```
public bool LastTransmitted {
  get {
    return _tracker.lastTransmitted;
  }
  set {
    _tracker.lastTransmitted = value;
    RaisePropertyChanged("LastTransmitted");
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

When i understand you right, you want that the Background of the `TextBlock` gets changed when the `LastTransmitted` property changes. TextBlock by itself has no Background-Property, so you have to put the TextBlock into an container like `Grid` or `StackPanel`.

Here´s a DataTemplate for your ListBox that does what you want.

```
<DataTemplate>
  <StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Style>
      <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
        <Style.Triggers>
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=LastTransmitted}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
          </DataTrigger>
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=LastTransmitted}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
          </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
    </StackPanel.Style>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding Path=Description}" />
  </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: I wish you could see the rest of my viewmodel, i literally Raise the property change every time. Every time but this time, what a silly mistake XD, that said i've added the property changed and still nothing seems to happen.

Comment: Still no avail i'm afraid. I'm trying to apply the styling to the textblock, should that be done differently? As the style targetting targets ListViewItem

Comment: @Shane.C i changed my answer. Take a look at it.

Comment: Works a charm as soon as i'd changed my threadlist type to a concurrent bag and handled manual refresh on item add. Thanks  : )

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface on your view model... you are setting the property value, but the Framework is not notifying the UI.

You can find out how to do this from the [How to: Implement Property Change Notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx) page at MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

The XAML doesn't know you've updated the value unless you tell it.  You need [**property change notification**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx).

Have your class implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) and define the `PropertyChanged` event handler. Then whenever you `set` something that the XAML should care about, fire off a `PropertyChanged` event with the name of the property you changed.

```
public class TrackerViewModel : ViewModelBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    readonly Tracker _tracker;

    public TrackerViewModel( Tracker tracker )
    {
        _tracker = tracker;
    }

    public bool LastTransmitted
    {
        get
        {
            return _tracker.lastTransmitted;
        }
        set
        {
            _tracker.lastTransmitted = value;
            OnPropertyChanged( "LastTransmitted" );
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged( string name )
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if( handler != null ) handler( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( name ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: I simply forgot to add the propertyChanged event, but after doing this i'm still seeing no result! i've updated my code

Comment: How do you set the DataContext? Because you've used `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MainWindowViewModel.TrackerCollection}"`, I assume your DataContext is set to something that contains a property called `MainWindowViewModel` which has a collection property called `TrackerCollection` which is full of `TrackerViewModel`s.  Make sure this is all correct.

Comment: Yeah, that's all correct.The binding works i'm sure because the textblock content is set to a binding in the same DataContext and that works fine. If i take the triggers out and just have the setter, it changes colour as expected, just not with the datatriggers. I can also verify that the property change triggers, with the OnPropertyChanged too.